# Why changing this array's value, in a function using pointers, is wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, reference

I was solving a revert array homework and, at some point, the code compiled, suddenly, after an (apparently unrelated) alteration, the code couldn't be compiled anymore.

***This one compiles***

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
#define fori(x, y) for(int i = x; i<y; i++)
using namespace std;

int vetor[MAX];

void inverterElemento(int* a, int* b){
     int* inverter;
     *inverter = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = *inverter;
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        vetor[i] = 7*i;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= MAX/2; k++){
        int a = vetor[k];
        int b = vetor[MAX-k-1];
        inverterElemento(&vetor[k], &vetor[MAX - k - 1]);
    }
    fori(0, MAX) cout << vetor[i] << " "; cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**This one gives `Bus error:10` issue:**

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 100
#define fori(x, y) for(int i = x; i<y; i++)
using namespace std;

int vetor[MAX];

void inverterElemento(int* a, int* b){
     int* inverter;
     *inverter = *a;
     *a = *b;
     *b = *inverter;
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        vetor[i] = 7*i;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k <= MAX/2; k++){

        inverterElemento(&vetor[k], &vetor[MAX - k - 1]);
    }
    fori(0, MAX) cout << vetor[i] << " "; cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why this 2 lines changes the outcome?

```
int a = vetor[k];
int b = vetor[MAX-k-1];
```

Comment: It's because the swap function uses an uninitialized pointer. `int* inverter` should be `int inverter`.

Comment: It's not crashing for the first version because some non-deterministic behavior of the compiler / environment you're using makes `inverter` point to valid memory in that version but not the other.

Answer (score 1):

In the following lines:

```c
     int* inverter;
     *inverter = *a;
```

`inverter` is declared as a pointer to `int` but there is no initial address to which it points (the content, i.e address, is undefined).

Should be:

```c
    int inverter;
    inverter = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = inverter;
```

Comment: Wow! I got it! Thanks!!